Junit listener is not triggered when running tests with maven command
I've run into the following issue, I have Rest Assured API Tests that use JUNIT Testign framework, I have added a TestExecutionListener that should print details about executed tests.
however when I run the tests thorugh the maven command:
`mvn test -Duri=http://localhost:8000/api`

This TestExecutionListener is not triggered.
When I run the test class by pressing " Play " button on IntelliJIDEA then the TestExecutionListener is triggered.
And when I run it again with maven command it is also triggered.
So, the problem is only when running the tests with maven command for the first time and then after running it locally it everything gets fixed, but this is not a solution for me because I need
everything to run on the first try of maven command because tests are run as a separate job of CI/CD Pipeline.
I've verfified that my project is using JAVA 8, and my JAVA HOME PATH is also pointing to HJAVA8
Not sure if this is helpful but will add here the listener that I have along with org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener file
org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener:
utils.listeners.RunnerExtension

public class RunnerExtension implements TestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {

        System.out.println("========STARTING============");
    }

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {

        System.out.println("========FINISHING=============");
    }

I tried running tests with maven command mvn test -Duri=http://localhost:8000/api and expected the
RunnerExtension that implements TestExecutionListener to be triggered. but it was not triggered.
and it is getting triggered only when I run tests through IntelliJ Idea directly
Additional info:
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.6/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
==
I have also run mvn test -X  -Duri=http://localhost:8000/api` in both cases when the TestExecutionListener was triggered and was not triggered and I didn't notice any difference in logs, so ib both cases it was using the same libraries,
==
The pom.xml file is as follows;
...
   <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <restassured.version>4.0.0</restassured.version>
        <junit.version>5.7.2</junit.version>
        <junit.dataprovider.version>2.4</junit.dataprovider.version>
        <allure-maven.version>2.10.0</allure-maven.version>
        <allure-junit5.version>2.14.0</allure-junit5.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.6</aspectj.version>
        <allure.version>2.17.1</allure.version>
        <allure.cmd.download.url>
            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline
        </allure.cmd.download.url>
        <wiremock.version>2.23.2</wiremock.version>
     </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
    plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <configurationParameters>
                            junit.jupiter.conditions.deactivate = *
                            junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true
                            junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default = per_class
                        </configurationParameters>
                    </properties>
                       <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>target/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
    </configuration>
                <dependencies>....
  <dependencies>


Please show the pom file... also the log output... which version of Maven, IntelliJ, JDK etc. are you using?

openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
Apache Maven 3.9.6
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.6/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_292, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_UA, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.16", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)
as for the logs I 've run mvn -X  and was no logs differen

<junit.version>5.7.2</junit.version>
<junit.dataprovider.version>2.4</junit.dataprovider.version>
<allure-maven.version>2.10.0</allure-maven.version>
<allure-junit5.version>2.14.0</allure-junit5.version>
<maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
==

org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-surefire-plugin
${maven-surefire-plugin.version}

Please edit your posting ... not in comments...

sorry, just updated it

I  found the solution thanks to comment of @Twaldigas under related topic
JUnit 5: Is it possible to set a TestExecutionListener in Maven Surefire Plugin?
I used this library:
https://github.com/google/auto/tree/main/service
( had to add a new dependency and update configuration of maven-compiler-plugin , anyway it's described in their documentation )
Then I added an annotation to the class that implements TestExecutionListener
So my code looks like this:
import org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener;
import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;

@AutoService(TestExecutionListener.class)
public class RunnerExtension implements TestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionStarted(TestPlan testPlan) {

        System.out.println("========STARTING============");
    }

    @Override
    public void testPlanExecutionFinished(TestPlan testPlan) {

        System.out.println("========FINISHING=============");
    }

With this approach the file
META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListen
is not needed at all !
